# excel index/match with merged cell

Tags: excel-formula

[Master Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa93N.jpg)

How should I set the formula to get the figures with multiple criteria in merged cell?
E.g. refer to the Master table, if I would like to know how many orders that Peter has made in Area 2 in Jan. I tried to use index match function, but didn't work out. 
The criteria should go through > select "order" in column A > "Area 1" in column B > "Peter" in Column C > to have the row number, and match "2017/Jan" in column D.
Can anyone suggest a formula to me?

Comment: Dealing with merged cells in formulas in a well-known tedious problem, **especially** when the formulas involve arrays, such as `Index/Match/SUMIF` etc. If you can't unmerge those cells, your best bet would be to use a hidden helper column.

Answer (score 1):

The same has been answered by A.S.H through comment, hence reflecting as unanswered.

Posting the answer behalf of **A.S.H**

Dealing with merged cells in formulas in a well-known tedious problem, especially when the formulas involve arrays, such as `Index / Match/ SUMIF` etc. If you can't `Unmerge` those cells, your best bet would be to use a hidden helper column.

**My Suggestions:**

Steps You Can Follow In These Scenarios

- Create Name Manager by entering the cell ranges manually.

`Formulas -> Name Manager -> New... -> Enter Group Name (Ex.Raw data) -> Select Where You Want To Apply the Scope -> Type Ranges as you required reference`s (ex. `=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4`)

When you typing the formula instead of array or match ranges you can directly use the Group Name that you have entered.

> You can create helper column to fix the issue.
>
> Type the cell ranges manually.
>
> Use Concatenate Methods.